# 3.0: Rearrange/restore menu bar?

Tags: interface, versions

Today I updated from 2.93 to 3.0 and noticed the Tool Settings menu has swapped places with the View/Select/Add/Object menu. How can I change it back? I am not opposed to installing an addon or manually editing files to do this.

The new layout:

[image: new layout]

How I want it:
[image: old layout]

I would also like to remove the translucent background from the lower level, but that's not as important.

Comment: It's an internal change you can't edit this, but you can make the translucent background transparent

Comment: @Karan actually interface is written on python. So you can change the layout

Comment: @Karan how do I make it transparent?

Comment: I found it, it's Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Theme Space > Header. Changing the alpha value to 0 makes the lower bar transparent without affecting the upper bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click (Right Mouse Button) on any element in the interface and choose "Edit source".

[image]

It will open the source file (text area should be somewhere)  where you can find where this button or switcher has been introduced.

So you can edit the file and rearrange elements and once you're done press <kbd>F3</kbd> ⇾ Reload scripts. If you do everything correctly, you should notice that interface changes. If not, probably, the interface will be broken completely, all buttons and menus will be gone. So that's why **backup** the file first.

Comment: But how can you change the position of VIEW3D_HT_tool_header to VIEW3D_HT_header and vise-versa?

Comment: I couldn't find it until I checked "Developer Extras" in the Interface settings. Looking at the code I don't know where to start, I was hoping I could rearrange pointers or something but it seems each button's function is written where it is.

Comment: OH! I forgot about Developer Extras! I apologize

Comment: Yes. Sure every element are here, so you can move and rearrange them.

Comment: I don't know enough about Python to get it to work right so unfortunately I guess I'll have to live with it for now. Thanks anyway